# How can i create ember handlebar helper for true or false condition

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

Here is my handlebar template...

```
{{#idType}}
  <label>{{unbound Model.viewData.name}}<span class="redTxt">*</span></label>
  <input type="text" name="" id="{{unbound Model.viewData.name}}">
{{/idType}}
```

In Ember view, I created one helper method like

```
Em.Handlebars.registerHelper("idType", function() {
    if(Model.viewData.selectGender === "Gender") {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
});
```

Here If it is true, then its displays true instead of my label and textfield.
Can you please help me to find a solution for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define a computed property in your controller/model as follows, you don't need a helper method for this

```
requiredGender: function(){
  //returning a boolean value
  return this.get('viewData.selectGender') === "Gender";
}.property('viewData.selectGender') // defining dependencies

{{#if requiredGender}}
  TRUE
{{else}}
  <label>{{unbound Model.viewData.name}}<span class="redTxt">*</span></label>
  <input type="text" name="" id="{{unbound Model.viewData.name}}">
{{/if}}
```